# If c# is typesafe language then why it is allowed to change type of object using dynamic and object keyword?

Tags: c#

Why this is allowed in C#?

```cs
dynamic abc = 123;
abc = 'ashwin';
```

We are changing type of object at runtime, but as we know C# is typesafe then why it allow us to do so?

Take a look at compiler output:

[image: Take a look at compiler output]

Comment: C# lets you write type-safe code. It also lets you write non-type-safe code in particular situations, using the `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: You could do the same with `object`, you didn't even need to involve `dynamic`. You are not changing types of any objects, you are putting a *different object* (a string) into a *container* (`abc`) that is compatible with that object (because `dynamic`/`object` are compatible with anything).

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, because C# requires to you to explicitly say “I *know* that the following operations treat values of different types the same, please go ahead anyway”. The compiler does not allow you to “accidentally” treat different types uniformly, you have to specify this explicitly — either by using a (universal) superclass such as `object`, or by using the `dynamic` keyword to defer type checking to runtime.